# serving pdf in request results in empty response

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Here is the code to fetch pdf from one server and serve it in servlet as response:

```
GAELogger.logInfo(LOG, "download request. url: " + downloadURLStr);

HTTPResponse fetchResponse = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService().fetch(new URL(downloadURLStr));

byte[] pdfContent = fetchResponse.getContent();
Integer totalLength = pdfContent.length;
String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());

GAELogger.logInfo(LOG, "writing. total: " + totalLength.toString());

response.reset();
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + ".pdf\"");
response.setHeader("Content-Length", totalLength.toString());

ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(pdfContent);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();

GAELogger.logInfo(LOG, "done.");
```

Here is the log of the request to serve pdf:

```
download request. url: http://someurl/test.pdf
writing. total: 43497
logInfo: done.
```

and sometimes the response is empty and chrome gives an error like this:

[image]

While sometimes it does serve the request and pdf is downloaded. I have tried multiple approches like:

```
String downloadURLStr = outputFiles.get(0).getUrl();
URL downloadURL = new URL(downloadURLStr);
URLConnection connection = downloadURL.openConnection();

InputStream inputStream = downloadURL.openStream();
OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
Integer totalLength = connection.getContentLength();

response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + id + ".pdf\"");
response.setHeader("Content-Length", totalLength.toString());

IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);

IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
```

which also fails. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't do anything on Google App Engine for quite some time, but back then (maybe 2 years ago) the GAE closed threads if they took too long. Maybe you should crosscheck the restrictions GAE makes and if they result in that strange behaviour. However this would answer why it sometimes work and sometimes not.

Comment: the problem is when is starts failing it consistently fails. and when it starts serving it does it consistently :( and the log tells it did everything. so i dont know wch restriction would be causing issue. 2013-07-05 03:42:01.423 - 2013-07-05 03:42:05.979 is request time and file size is 4.5KB. server is completely idle. so i dont understand wch other limit i might b hitting.